# how to obtain available free space on sdcard from android application?

Tags: android

I am developing an android application where i need to determine the free space available on the sdcard. Can anyone give me some suggestion regarding this please.

thanks
kaisar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
StatFs stat = new StatFs(sdcard.getAbsolutePath());
long available = stat.getAvailableBlocks() * (long) stat.getBlockSize();
```

Answer (score 1):

You may have to restat to get accurate results:

```
StatFs stat = new StatFs(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
stat.restat(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
long available = ((long) stat.getAvailableBlocks() * (long) stat.getBlockSize());
```

Comment: Why should one restat? I saw this suggestion elsewhere too but no explanation of why.

Comment: I am not entirely sure, but I think the OS or JVM caches this data for performance reasons (any disk IO is going to be far, far slower then normal processing).  Doing a restat forces a refresh of the data.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this function

```
 private boolean is_sdCardSaveToUse(){

    /**default disk cache size in bytes*/
    final int DEFAULT_DISK_CACHE_SIZE = 1024 * 1024 * 10; //10 MB

    /**get sdCard state*/
    String sdCardState = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

    /**check if the sdCard is mounted*/
    /**check if we can write to sdCard*/if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(sdCardState)) {
        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(sdCardState)) {
            Log.d("sdCard", "mounted readOnly");
        } else {
            Log.d("sdCard", "mounted readWrite");

            /**get free usable space in bytes */
            long freeUsableSpace = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getUsableSpace();
            int temp = Math.round(((float) freeUsableSpace / 1024) / 1024); //convert from bytes to MB.
            Log.d("usableSpace= ", Integer.toString(temp) + " MB");

            if (freeUsableSpace > DEFAULT_DISK_CACHE_SIZE){
                return  true;
            } else {
                Log.d("sdCard","not enough space");
                return  false;
            }

        }

    } else{
        Log.d("sdCard","not mounted");
        return false;
    }

   return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, but is there any special reason not to use StatFs class which is used in others' answers?