# How to know the available disk space on android/ios?

Tags: android, ios, delphi, firemonkey

before to save a file to the cache directory i want to know how much space are available on the device (especially the space available where the cache directory is located). How to do this on android and ios ? i m on delphi berlin.

Comment: You're going to have to implement platform-specific code for each OS; there is no RTL function that does so for every targeted OS. There's an example of doing it for Android [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4171173/62576), but it's not Delphi code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok, here is the solution for all plateform (taken from https://github.com/Zeus64/alcinoe) :

```
  {$IFDEF ANDROID}
  aStatFS := TJStatFs.JavaClass.init(StringToJstring(aDir));
  if (TJBuild_VERSION.JavaClass.SDK_INT < 18 {Android 4.3 - JELLY_BEAN_MR2}) then aTmpAvailableSpace := aStatFS.getBlockSize * aStatFS.getAvailableBlocks
  else aTmpAvailableSpace := aStatFS.getAvailableBytes;
  aStatFS := nil;
  {$ELSEIF defined(IOS) or defined(_MACOS)}
  aFileManager := TNSFileManager.Wrap(TNSFileManager.OCClass.defaultManager);
  aDict := aFileManager.attributesOfFileSystemForPath(StrToNSStr(aDir), nil);
  if aDict = nil then aTmpAvailableSpace := 0
  else begin
    aPointer := aDict.objectForKey((CocoaNSStringConst(FoundationFwk, 'NSFileSystemFreeSize') as ILocalObject).GetObjectID);
    if Assigned(aPointer) then aTmpAvailableSpace := TNSNumber.Wrap(aPointer).unsignedLongLongValue
    else aTmpAvailableSpace := 0;
  end;
  {$ELSEIF defined(MSWINDOWS)}
  aDiskDrive := ALupperCaseU(AlStringReplaceU(ExtractFileDrive(aDir), ':', '', []));
  if length(aDiskDrive) = 1 then aTmpAvailableSpace := DiskFree(ord(aDiskDrive[low(aDiskDrive)]) - $40)
  else aTmpAvailableSpace := 0;
  {$ENDIF}
```

Comment: Downvote for no source for TJALStatFs. I expect I know where it is, however you should add a reference to it

Comment: you are right I forget to add the reference to the source, so their it is:  https://github.com/Zeus64/alcinoe ...

Comment: I meant in the actual answer