# Delphi Tokyo Android: How do I get the Free Available Disk Space?

Tags: android, delphi, free, space

I've found this information [here](https://github.com/FMXExpress/android-object-pascal-wrapper/blob/c72e8dd237e4bb5a58e7c443680711ee75c4e8c0/android-23/android.mtp.MtpStorageInfo.pas), but I seem to be unable to get it working in my application.

Tried to access it using TJMtpStorageInfo.JavaClass.getFreeSpace; but that does not seem to work.

Found another link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41201424/how-to-know-the-available-disk-space-on-android-ios), but they don't include where TJALStatFs comes from or the uses clause.  TJALStatFs is undefined.

I'm just stuck on figuring this one out.  Does anyone have source code they can provide for Delphi Tokyo Android programming so that I can get the available free space on the Android Device?

I'm debugging on Moto G4 Play Android version 6.0.1

Comment: The missing link for TJALStatFs is here: https://github.com/Zeus64/alcinoe/blob/master/source/ALAndroidApi.pas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delphi Tokyo 10.2.2 version w/ Android 6.0.1:

Found this link [android.os.StatFs](https://github.com/FMXExpress/android-object-pascal-wrapper/blob/c72e8dd237e4bb5a58e7c443680711ee75c4e8c0/android-19/android.os.StatFs.pas) which i need to include into my project.

My simple program I was designing would fill all the space on android with random data.

Here is the source code I used to do this.  Warning: Code may still be buggy, but currently seems to be doing what it's suppose to.  The main objective here was to show full source code for which I got it working.  I personally hate it when people give partial source code and you've got to figure out all the rest.

Thread's don't like to update memo pad, or any of the GUI.. so I commented them out.  I've got to create a special TThread annoymous procedure, but currently I was working just to get the application to function.  Please forgive me, it's a bit sloppy coding.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs,
  IdBaseComponent, IdThreadComponent, FMX.StdCtrls, FMX.Layouts,
  FMX.Controls.Presentation, FMX.ScrollBox, FMX.Memo, System.IOUtils,
  AndroidAPI.JNIBridge,
  Androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes,
  android.os.StatFs,
  Posix.Unistd;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Memo1: TMemo;
    Button1: TButton;
    Layout1: TLayout;
    AniIndicator1: TAniIndicator;
    Layout2: TLayout;
    STOP: TButton;
    Layout3: TLayout;
    Label1: TLabel;
    IdThreadComponent1: TIdThreadComponent;
    Button2: TButton;
    procedure IdThreadComponent1Run(Sender: TIdThreadComponent);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure STOPClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure IdThreadComponent1Stopped(Sender: TIdThreadComponent);
    procedure IdThreadComponent1Terminate(Sender: TIdThreadComponent);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
    breakit: boolean;
    //createnewrandfileActive: boolean;
    copydataActive: boolean;
    procedure CopyData();
    procedure CreateNewRandFile(Fsize : Int64);
    function CheckDiskSize(aDir : String): Int64;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

uses Androidapi.Helpers;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  breakit := false;
  IdThreadComponent1.Start;
end;

function TForm1.CheckDiskSize(aDir : String): Int64;
var aStatFS : JStatFs;
    //aTmpAvailableSpace : Int64;
begin
  aStatFS := TJStatFs.JavaClass.init(StringToJString(aDir));
  //aTmpAvailableSpace := aStatFS.getBlockSize * aStatFS.getAvailableBlocks;
  //aTmpAvailableSpace := aStatFS.getAvailableBytes;
  //aStatFS := nil;
  result := aStatFS.getAvailableBytes;
end;

procedure TForm1.CreateNewRandFile(Fsize : Int64);
var
  FileStream1: TFileStream;
  RandomFileToCopy : string;
  Rand1 : Int64;
begin
  //createnewrandfileActive := true;
  //memo1.BeginUpdate;
  //memo1.Lines.Add('Begin CreateNewRandFile');
  //memo1.EndUpdate;
  // create random file
  if Fsize > CheckDiskSize(TPath.GetTempPath) then Fsize := CheckDiskSize(TPath.GetTempPath);

  //memo1.lines.add('free space: ' + IntToStr(CheckDiskSize((TPath.GetTempPath))));
  //memo1.lines.add('create file size: ' + IntToStr(Fsize));
  Randomize;
  RandomFileToCopy := TPath.GetTempPath + TPath.DirectorySeparatorChar + 'random.fil';
  //memo1.Lines.Add(RandomFileToCopy);
  if FileExists(RandomFileToCopy) = false then
  begin
    FileStream1 := TFileStream.Create(RandomFileToCopy, fmCreate or fmOpenWrite or fmShareDenyWrite);
    try
      while FileStream1.Size < Fsize do
      begin
        Rand1 := Random(2147483600);
        FileStream1.WriteBuffer(Rand1, SizeOf(Rand1));
        //Label1.Text := IntToStr(FileStream1.Size);
        if breakit = true then break;
      end;
    finally
      FileStream1.Free;
    end;
  end;
  //memo1.lines.add('free space ' + IntToStr(CheckDiskSize(TPath.GetTempPath)));
  //memo1.BeginUpdate;
  //memo1.Lines.Add('End of CreateNewRandFile');
 // memo1.EndUpdate;

  //createnewrandfileActive := false;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  CreateNewRandFile(128000000); // create a 128mb file
end;

procedure TForm1.CopyData();
var
  DriveStr : String;
  RandomFileToCopy : String;
  FileNameCounter : integer;
  FolderCounter : integer;
  FolderName : string;
  FolderArea : string;
  RandomFileName : String;
begin
  copydataActive := true;

  breakit := false;

  FileNameCounter := 0;
  FolderCounter := 0;

  //memo1.BeginUpdate;
  //memo1.Lines.Add('Begin of Copy');
  //memo1.EndUpdate;

  DriveStr := TPath.GetTempPath() + TPath.DirectorySeparatorChar;

  //memo1.Lines.Add('DriveStr ' + DriveStr);

  RandomFileToCopy := DriveStr + 'random.fil';

  //memo1.Lines.Add('RandomFileToCopy ' + RandomFileToCopy);

  //memo1.Lines.Add('Creating Random File...');

  // create random file
  CreateNewRandFile(64000000); //64 mb file

  inc(FolderCounter);
  FolderName := 'rand' + IntToStr(FolderCounter);
  //memo1.Lines.Add('FolderName ' + FolderName);

  FolderArea := TPath.GetTempPath() + TPath.DirectorySeparatorChar + FolderName;
  //memo1.Lines.Add('FolderArea ' + FolderArea);

  while DirectoryExists(FolderArea) = true do
  begin
    inc(FolderCounter);
    FolderName := 'rand' + IntToStr(FolderCounter);
    FolderArea := TPath.GetTempPath() + TPath.DirectorySeparatorChar + FolderName;

    if breakit = true then break;
  end;

  TDirectory.CreateDirectory(FolderArea);

  while CheckDiskSize(FolderArea) > 0 do
  begin
    if breakit = true then break;

    //memo1.Lines.Add('CreateDir(FolderName) ' + FolderName);

    //FolderArea := FolderArea + TPath.DirectorySeparatorChar;
    //memo1.Lines.Add('FolderArea ' + FolderArea);

    RandomFileName := FolderArea + 'ran' + IntToStr(FileNameCounter) + '.fil';
    //memo1.Lines.Add('RandomFileName ' + RandomFileName);

    FileNameCounter := 0;

    while FileNameCounter<126 do
    begin
      inc(FileNameCounter);

      //while FileExists(RandomFileName) do
      //begin
      RandomFileName := FolderArea + TPath.DirectorySeparatorChar + 'ran' + IntToStr(FileNameCounter) + '.fil';
      //end;

      //memo1.Lines.Add(RandomFileName);
      //Label1.Text := RandomFileName;

      try
        //if FileExists(RandomFileName) = true then DeleteFile(RandomFileName);
        TFile.Copy(RandomFileToCopy, RandomFileName);
      Except
        On E: Exception Do
        begin
          //memo1.BeginUpdate;
          showmessage(E.ClassName + ' ERROR: ' + E.Message);
          //memo1.EndUpdate;
          breakit := true;
        end;
      end;

      if breakit = true then break;

    end;

    while DirectoryExists(FolderArea) = true do
    begin
      inc(FolderCounter);
      FolderName := 'rand' + IntToStr(FolderCounter);
      FolderArea := TPath.GetTempPath() + TPath.DirectorySeparatorChar + FolderName;

      if breakit = true then break;
    end;

    TDirectory.CreateDirectory(FolderArea);

  end;

  //memo1.BeginUpdate;
  //memo1.Lines.Add('End of Copy');
  //memo1.EndUpdate;

  //memo1.Lines.Add('Deleting Created Fillers');

  copydataActive := false;

end;

procedure TForm1.IdThreadComponent1Run(Sender: TIdThreadComponent);
begin
  if breakit = true then
    begin
      IdThreadComponent1.Stop;
      exit;
    end;

  if copydataActive = false then
  begin
    AniIndicator1.Enabled := true;
    CopyData();
  end;
  sleep(500);
end;

procedure TForm1.IdThreadComponent1Stopped(Sender: TIdThreadComponent);
begin
  AniIndicator1.Enabled := false;
end;

procedure TForm1.IdThreadComponent1Terminate(Sender: TIdThreadComponent);
begin
  AniIndicator1.Enabled := false;
end;

procedure TForm1.STOPClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  breakit := true;
  IdThreadComponent1.Stop;
end;

end.
```